# How to verify if a variable is equal to an other variable or a Windows variable in batch files?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, environment-variables

I am making a "locked" batch file that only certain user can use so what I am doing right now is to check the condition if what the `user` write is `==` to `%username%` or other variable like this:

```bash
if /i "%Nom%" == %UserName% Goto :Next2
```

Which `%Nom%` is what the user write.
I have tried multiple ways but I cant find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

```bash
if /i  "?"  ==  "?"  ( true ) else ( false ) // return condition True
if /i  "?"  ==   ?   ( true ) else ( false ) // return condition False
if /i  [?]  ==  [?]  ( true ) else ( false ) // return condition True
if /i  [?]  ==  "?"  ( true ) else ( false ) // return condition False
if /i  [?]  ==  [?]  ( true ) else ( false ) // return condition True
if /i "[?]" == ["?"] ( true ) else ( false ) // return condition False
if /i "{?}" == "{?}" ( true ) else ( false ) // return condition True
if /i "/?/" ==  /?/  ( true ) else ( false ) // return condition False
if /i  \?\  ==  \?\  ( true ) else ( false ) // return condition True
if /i  /?/  == "/?/" ( true ) else ( false ) // return condition False
```

This will always return a **`False`** condition for the comparison of **`"string"`** *equals* **`string`**, because in the comparison the double quotes are a component of the character string, and will be compared in its entirety with the quotes.

Note that the quotes are not composing any escape and/or any complement to the `if` command, but rather in the execution being part of what is being compared, so everything that comes after the `if`,`if /i`, `if Not` or `ìf /i not`, allways will be object of comparison with what comes after the equal, with or without `""`, and/or `[]`, `{}`, etc...

---

So, your are using:

```bash
if /i   "?"   ==       ?      ... 
if /i "%Nom%" == "%UserName%" Goto :Next2
```

**P.S. 1.:** ***`"Something Inside Double Quotes"`*** compared to ***`Something Outside Double Quotes`***, where it should be: ***`"Something Inside Double Quotes"`*** compared to ***`"Something Inside Double Quotes"`***

---

**P.S. 2.:** For **numerical** comparisons (of **`integers`**), use:

```bash
if integer EQU integer ...
if    1    EQU    1    ...
 
                EQU : Equal
                NEQ : Not equal

                LSS : Less than <
                LEQ : Less than or Equal <=

                GTR : Greater than >
                GEQ : Greater than or equal >=

                This 3 digit syntax is necessary because the > and <
                symbols are recognised as redirection operators
IF will only parse numbers when one of (EQU, NEQ, LSS, LEQ, GTR, GEQ) is used.
The == comparison operator always results in a string comparison.
```

- Source:  **[ss64.com/nt/if.html](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [`Goto :lable /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [Where does **`GOTO :EOF`** return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://superuser.com/a/514298/969781)